# Search_fields in django python

Tags: python, django-admin

I was wondering how I am able to use a foreign key to preform a search for example

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 127)
    description = models.TextField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 127)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.code

class ProductLot(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    lot_no = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 127)
    incoming = models.IntegerField()
    commited = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.IntegerField()
    reorder = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code + " - " + self.product.name + " - " + self.lot_no

class LotComment(models.Model):
     product_lot = models.ForeignKey(ProductLot)
     comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
     comment_text = models.TextField()
     created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_lot.product.code + " - " + 
           self.product_lot.product.name + " - " + 
           self.product_lot.lot_no + " - " + str(self.created_date)
```

than in my admin.py file I have

```
from CMS.Inventory.models import Product

class padmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields=['name', 'description', 'code', 'lot_no' ]
admin.site.register(Product, padmin)
```

but I want for 'LotComments' to be able to use the same search fields that 'Product' can as for code ect.

Hope I explained this well

Answer (score 17):

You can specify related field searches in the admin `search_fields` the same way you do on Django querysets. Check on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields). For the `LotComments` object, the `search_fields` would look something like:

```
search_fields = ['product_lot__product__name', 
                 'product_lot__product__description', 
                 'product_lot__product__code',
                 'product_lot__lot_no']
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answers. I would like to suggest [Django Admin advance filters](https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters)

User this plugin to add advance search and save advance search support.
Also in your case foreign key fields can be mapped to a name.

```
class padmin(AdminAdvancedFiltersMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    advanced_filter_fields = ('name', ('product_lot__product__name', 'Product name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For referencing the foreign key use `__` (two underscores):

```
from CMS.Inventory.models import Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields=['name__name', 'description', 'code', 'lot_no' ]
    admin.site.register(Product, padmin)
```