# Using __unicode__ of a model as a search field in admin form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a way of including model's **__unicode__** method to **search_fields** tuple? I don't want to create special field for storing result of the **__unicode__** in the model, because this value depends of the several other models...

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, because fields mentioned in `search_fields` tuple are used to construct sql query

Look https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py lines 349-370

**UPD.** Well, you can create another field and store value of `__unicode__` method there. Probably it looks ugly and inefficient but this allows you to filter database column. 
Give me more information how `__unicode__` method looks.

**UPD2** Your `unicode` method:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s%s%s%s-%s%s" % (
        self.factory.republic.code.upper(),
        self.factory.location.region and self.factory.location.region.code or '00', 
        self.factory.location.code, 
        self.factory.code, 
        self.kind.code, 
        self.code
    )
```

Django `search_fields` operates his ORM methods so if you cannot perform 
`Catalog.objects.filter(**lookup_queries)`, you will not be able to do that with `search_fields` in admin. Unfortunately.

You `unicode` method is really specific with join of 6 tables and other program logic. Searching this field will be complicated in SQL language, and will not use index. Try to save result in db column and update when related fields update too.

Comment: Well, maybe you know how customize search?

Comment: "%s%s%s%s-%s%s" % (self.factory.republic.code.upper(), self.factory.location.region and self.factory.location.region.code or '00', self.factory.location.code, self.factory.code, self.kind.code, self.code)

Comment: It's a catalog id. If I make this field, I have to hook modifications of all related models.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I did require something similar recently. 
As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730547/1211429) `search_fields` *only works with attributes that represent columns in the database, not with properties*.

However if your `__unicode__` function *depends of the [fields within] several other models* look at 
[this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2106162/1211429) which explains how to specify [related field searches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) in the admin search_fields the same way you do on Django querysets.

Comment: I saw the answer with related fields search... But my **\__unicode__** is combination of the several tables, so search must be done with them altogether.